# What is quartz.serializer.type in quartz.net?

Tags: .net, quartz.net, quartz

When read the 3.x documents of quartz.net,

I see a property named "quartz.serializer.type" with value "binary" - which not see in the 2.x documents.

So, what does it mean?

Comment: Check this https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/migration-guide.html

Comment: @deramachine Great! That's what I need. Thanks.